# Spark Video Player null Object Error After Playback Error

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, video-player

I'm having a problem with the Spark VideoPlayer. If the player encounters a playback error (maybe due to it not being able to play the file) and I then try to set the source again I get a null object error. The error occurs here:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at spark.components::VideoDisplay/cleanUpSource()
    E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\VideoDisplay.as:1956]
```

which points to

```
videoPlayer.displayObject.visible = true;
```

where the `displayObject` is `null`.

I can't seem to find a way around this problem other than ditching the `VideoPlayer` component and creating my own.

I've seen a few post relating to this problem but I've not found a solution which work for me.

Comment: Interesting problem. From looking at the source, there doesn't seem to be a simple work around. What are some of the reasons the media is not able to be played? I see two work arounds that are better than writing your own video player: 1) create the `VideoDisplay` object dynamically (not in MXML) and add it to some place-holder container in your MXML document ... then when the error happens, throw away the original `VideoDisplay` and make a new one; 2) Try to prevent the original error from happening by validating the source before you set it on the `VideoDisplay`.

Comment: or grab the class from [HERE](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/components/VideoDisplay.as) and fix it and use it instead.  :)

Comment: Apologies for late reply, was working on another project. @Sunil D: I used this method to tackle the problem.

Comment: @Jason Reeves: You are quite right but sadly don't have the time right now.